# Best way to send notifications on react native expo

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo

I doing a application with react native, expo and firebase.

I want to send notifications on my device but I would like to know the best way to do it.

I got the expo token and device token , so I can send notifications on the ‘https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send' url .

I could do a firebase cloud function that send to this url the notifications.

But I would like to know if we have another way to do it ?

I can do a function that listen to change on the realtime database with the « on » function to make notifications.

Or use some socketIo with firebase function ?

Or maybe use the device token ?

I don’t like to use a lots of external service, if I could use the firebase cloud message it would be good.

If you guys have some tips or advice.

Thanks for all help.